# Confidence Interval for Some (But Not All) Interaction Terms in a Polynomial Interacted with a Binary Treatment

Tags: r, time-series, regression, confidence-interval, r-marginaleffects

I am looking for help estimating the effect of a third order polynomial term -- *over and above the linear term* at different values of the independent variable `x`. While I can estimate the point estimate, I am not sure how to calculate the confidence interval. I am thinking that marginal effects and the `marginaleffects` package may be the answer here -- but this is relatively new to me am not sure how to put this together.

If you have a different package, formula, or code that seems like the right answer, I'm definitely interested in that too! The general application here is an unexpected event design / interrupted time series using social science survey data.

Here is a reproducible example. In this example, there is a running variable `X` ranging between about `x = -2.5` and `x = 2.5` and the outcome variable `Y`. There are two quantities of interest:

1. The initial effect at `x = 0` (i.e. the jump)
2. The decay effect (i.e. the extra effect over and above the linear slope that occurred before the effect

In this example, the outcome variable `Y` is a stepwise function of `X`. I am using a third order polynomial to approximate this function, which as the designer of the simulation we know, even though it is incorrect.

Here is a figure (produced by the code below) that visualizes the simulated data (blue dots), the original trajectory (dashed orange line), and the third order polynomial (black line).

[image: Figure of simulated data, original trajectory, and third order polynomial]

... and here is the code

```
library(margins)
library(tidyverse)


set.seed(1900)

# Create Data
N <- 200
quad <- data.frame(x = rnorm(N)) %>% 
  mutate(post = as.integer(x > 0),
         x_sq = x^2,
         x_th = x^3)

# Create outcome (stepwise outcome with slight upward slope, jump, gradual decrease back to original slope)
quad$y <- with(quad, 0.002 * x + 0.05 * post - 0.05 * x * post * (x <= 1) - 0.05 * (x > 1))

# Visualize outcome
plot(quad$x, quad$y)

# Specify model (third order polynomial)

mod_quad <- lm(formula = y ~ x + x_sq + x_th + post + post * x + post * x_sq + post * x_th, data = quad)

# Plot Predictions

plot_predictions(mod_quad, by = "x", vcov = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(data = quad,
             aes(x = x, y = y),
             color = "blue",
             alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(data = tibble(x = seq(min(quad$x), max(quad$x), 0.01),
                          y = x * 0.002),
            aes(x = x, y = y),
            linetype = "dashed",
            color = "darkorange") +
  theme_bw()
```

Thank you for your help! Let me know if there are any clarifying questions.

Comment: Just FYI, you don’t need to manually calculate polynomials or explicitly specify lower-order terms / main effects in models. ie, you could simplify your formula to `y ~ post * poly(x, 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not hardcode the polynomial terms. To compute the standard errors, `marginaleffects` requires numerical derivatives which are obtained by slightly tweaking the value of `x`. But when you hardcode the polynomial terms, `marginaleffects` tweaks `x` but only the `x` column is affected, and not `x_sq`, `x_th`, etc.

Instead, use the `poly()` function in the model fitting call, as suggested in comments:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(marginaleffects)
set.seed(1900)

N <- 200
quad <- data.frame(x = rnorm(N)) %>% 
  mutate(post = as.integer(x > 0),
         x_sq = x^2,
         x_th = x^3)

quad$y <- with(quad, 0.002 * x + 0.05 * post - 0.05 * x * post * (x <= 1) - 0.05 * (x > 1))

mod <- lm(formula = y ~ post * poly(x, 3), data = quad)

plot_predictions(mod, condition = "x")  +
  geom_point(data = quad, aes(x, y))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! Great point about not hard-coding the other terms (oops). It's hard to tell from this figure -- but is the black line representing the effect of both the linear trend *and the polynomial* -- or is it truly giving the effect of just the post-event terms (i.e. without the linear trend from before)? The goal here is to be able to say, "The event at `x=0` caused an Z% increase in y at `x=0` but a `Z*` effect at `x=0.25`, `x=0.5`..." and so on. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, I used the same function as in your original post: `plot_predictions()`. This function plots predictions. If you want a "slope" or a "comparison" --- which is more like the idea of "effect" you expressed here --- then use the `plot_comparisons()` or `plot_slopes()` functions. Those are well documented, and the website includes detailed tutorials and examples: https://marginaleffects.com

Comment: Perfect, thank you Vincent! I appreciate your (very quick) help on this.